# Impersonation with ManagementClass to launch Remote Process (VB)

Tags: vb.net, wmi, remote-access, basic

This code launches a program remotely. The problem I'm having is with access privileges, so I need to use impersonation in order to pass admin privileges with the program launch command/query. I don't know how to include impersonation with this, and I couldn't find anything useful on Google. I've tried things like connection options but I haven't been able to get anything to work. Any ideas?

```
    Dim sCmd As String = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" ' & txtData.Text.Trim

    ' add a reference to System.Management in Solution Explorer

    Dim wmi As ManagementClass
    Dim wmi_in, wmi_out As ManagementBaseObject
    Dim retValue As Integer


    Try
        wmi = New ManagementClass("\\" & "ComputerName" & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
        ' get the parameters to the Create method
        wmi_in = wmi.GetMethodParameters("Create")


        ' fill in the command line plus any command-line arguments
        ' NOTE: the command can NOT be on a network resource!
        wmi_in("CommandLine") = sCmd
        ' do it!
        wmi_out = wmi.InvokeMethod("Create", wmi_in, Nothing)
        ' get the return code.  This not the return code of the
        ' application... it's a return code for the WMI method
        retValue = Convert.ToInt32(wmi_out("returnValue"))
        Select Case retValue
            Case 0
                ' success!
            Case 2
                Throw New ApplicationException("Access denied")
            Case 3
                Throw New ApplicationException("Insufficient privilege")
            Case 8
                Throw New ApplicationException("Unknown failure")
            Case 9
                Throw New ApplicationException("Path not found")
            Case 21
                Throw New ApplicationException("Invalid parameter")
            Case Else
                Throw New ApplicationException("Unknown return code " & retValue)
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("sd" & ": Can't create the process. " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dim remoteServer as string = "myServer"
RemoteStart(remoteServer, {"notepad.exe"})

Function RemoteStart(ByVal Server As String, ByVal sProcess As Object)
    Try
        Dim connOptions As ConnectionOptions = New ConnectionOptions()
        connOptions.Username = domain & "\" & username
        connOptions.Password = password
        connOptions.EnablePrivileges = True
        Dim theScope As ManagementScope = New ManagementScope("\\" & Server & "\root\cimv2", connOptions)
        Dim theClass As New ManagementClass(theScope, New ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), New ObjectGetOptions())
        theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", sProcess)
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show(Err.Description, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function
```